# "git update-git-for-windows" error: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate

Tags: windows, git, https, command-line, ssl-certificate

I am trying to update Git in Windows 10 with the command `git update-git-for-windows`, but I am facing the same issue as this person: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3930.

I ultimately uninstalled Git to download the newest version, instead of using `git update-git-for-windows`. I tried to run the same command with the the up-to-date version of Git just to see if the command would work, and I am now getting another error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

I am not using a VPN and I configured Git to use OpenSSL for HTTPS connections. I searched for other articles and it seemed that people were having certificate problems while running other commands like `git clone/push/pull`. I can run those commands fine, it's just `git update-git-for-windows` is giving me this error. I'm just wondering if anyone knows why I am getting this error and how I can solve it? (Other than disabling the check with `git config --global http.schannelCheckRevoke false`. I don't want to do this since this is not safe.)

I'm using Windows 10 and my Git version is `2.42.0.windows.1`.

Comment: May be the default Windows curl version used for update checking/downloading was replaced or reconfigured so an older version of curl is used that has problems with HTTPS?

Comment: Unfortunately even after updating curl to the newest version (8.2.1) I'm still getting the same error. Seems to have to do with CRL checking (thus related to HTTP/HTTPS connection). It may actually be a `destination unreachable error` as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4078), but I'm not using a proxy, and turning off firewall didn't help...

Comment: same issue here, I tried this and it worked (directly from the git for windows install page): Install winget tool if you don't already have it, then type this command in command prompt or Powershell.
winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget